# skip whatsapp restore on temporary phone but keep files for restore on next phone?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, restore, google-drive

I broke phone A last night and borrowed a phone B from a friend. It was very little storage so I don't have space to restore all my whatsapp data via google drive (the files are already there). I am waiting for phone C (replacement phone) to come, and would like to restore all messages on phone C when it comes.

If I skip restore on phone B (the low storage temporary phone), will I lose the ability to restore messages (even if I miss a few days that are on phone B)  on phone C? i.e. will skip delete everything and prevent restoration in future phone C?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No.  If you want to do this, you need to first go to settings in Google Drive, go to apps and disconnect whatsapp.

Then skip the restore.

It automatically overwrites your old one.

I had the same situation, followed the advice in the first comment and lost 1.7G of precious data including many pictures I have saved nowhere else :(

Answer (score 1):

If you enable sync with G Drive for chat backup in Phone B, then you cannot restore the backup.

Otherwise, you can restore in Phone C but the chats you have made from Phone C will not be there.